# Trouble hosting Express.js app on LAN network

Tags: node.js, express, networking

I've been trying to host an express.js server from my windows labtop onto my lan network so other devices on the router can visit the site also, here are my troubles:

```js
let express = require("express")
let app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello")
})

app.listen(80, "the ip I got")
```

I know all of this code is correct but the ip i'm putting into listen(), how i'm getting my ip is i'm going to cmd.exe and entering in ipconfig, then i'm using the address listed under "IPv4 address". If someone could help me get the right ip address to host on my lan network that would be great.

When I host the server on that address it acts as localhost and works when I visit the IP address in my browser but not for other devices connected to my router.

Comment: Try listening on all devices using ip `0.0.0.0`, also check if your windows firewall or router do not block traffic to your machine. I assume you can bind to port 80, however try changing port to something larger than 1024, like 3000 and check if it changes anything.

Comment: @Anastazy I’ve changed the port to 3000, listening on 0.0.0.0 without any errors. What IP address do I use to connect to my express server?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` address just means that your server binds and listens on all available interfaces, so use the IP address assigned to that computer by the router (usually DHCP server assigns IP addresses automatically). As you said, you can check the IP with `ipconfig` command in IPv4 section (ensure you are looking at the correct interface, if you have more than one network card). You can also check IP addresses assigned to devices in your router settings (usually you can login to your router by typing 192.168.1.1 in the browser).

Answer (score 1):

Verify your firewall rules. I have this problem too and turning firewall off to test it works.

Answer (score 0):

- use this code :

  ```
  let port = 3000
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Iam ready at port : " + port)
  })
  ```
- instead of : `app.listen(80, "the ip I got")`

Answer (score 0):

- First, assign static IP for your laptop.
- Then change the code as below

`let express = require("express")
let app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello")
})

app.listen(80,()=>{
    console.log("Server Started")
})`


 - Then try HTTP://localhost in your browser. it should work, after that try to access using other devices using your static IP. if not working check the firewall settings and allow port 80